# Where to put <a-assets> inside <a-scene>

Tags: html, ios, iphone, aframe

Hi to Aframe community,

I am developing an interactive 360 video with aframe.
It works great until I ran into a strange issue with iphone recently. And this problem ONLY happen on iphone(iOS12+ latest safari/chrome). Any other device (Ipad,Mac,PC,Android) has no issue at all.

The scene WOULD NOT display correctly on iphone if I put `<a-assets>` BEFORE `<a-camera>`

```
<a-scene>
     <a-assets>
        //my code here
     </a-assets>
             <a-entity camera id="camera" look-controls wasd-controls-enabled="false" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" touchEnable="true">
             <a-plane> position="0 0 -1"<a-plane>
             </a-entity>
     //some more code here...
</a-scene>
```

But if I put my `<a-assets>` AFTER `<a-camera>`, it will display as its intended.

```
<a-scene>
             <a-entity camera id="camera" look-controls wasd-controls-enabled="false" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" touchEnable="true">
             <a-plane> position="0 0 -1"<a-plane>
             </a-entity>
     <a-assets>
        //my code here
     </a-assets>
     //some more code here...
</a-scene>
```

The difference between this two different version of coding  is the `<a-plane>` inside `<a-camera>` would disappear or out of its position when `<a-assets>` load first.

I must stress on this problem ONLY occur in iphone. (Ipad and mac is no problem).
My question is: Is it ALRIGHT putting the `<a-assets>` not on top of HTML `<a-scene>`? Would it affect its ability to Pre-load the assets? or any undesire complication?? more importantly, WHY and WHAT make it only iphone has this problem.  thankyou

Comment: Notice that your HTML is not valid you have two opening `<a-assets>` tags instead of `<a-assets></a-assets>`

Comment: thanks to point it out. bit of typo